# Two civicrm contacts have become "mixed" somehow

Tags: contacts, user-account, user

I have a very odd situation.

I am user 1 in drupal and contact 25,000 in my civicrm. My contact record has a little /1 which links to my drupal record. My name is correct.

I am currently logged in.

However whenever I make changes to another contact record, if records the change as having been made by another contact in the civicrm database, let's say 25,001. This contact does not have a /x and there is no drupal record for this person. However when I try to delete this record it says I am logged in as that person so I can't delete them.

I am wondering if there is a table in the mysql of civicrm which matches the civi and drupal contacts up. Or indeed if there is some other thing I could look at to start trouble shooting.

Thought very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a table civicrm_uf_match but also during certain situations it will match on email. So check both those things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the two records have different email addresses. In the uf table (thanks for pointing out) I have connecting record with drupal id 1. My civicrm contact id is correct in the uf table. I am completely baffled!

Comment: Interestingly I have just tried logging in via another browser and was successful. When I created a contact in that broswer the contact is created by me - not the mystery contact (as shown by the change log)Presumably this suggests some kind of cookie or cache issue in my browser?

Comment: Yes that sounds like some cookie/session crossover.

Comment: I have been and deleted the cookies associated with this one site and this has resolved it. How strange! Thanks for your response